# Jquery UI Accordian - Collapse All Button

Tags: jquery

I'm using Jquery UI Accordian for the first time, and so far it's been pretty simple. However, I've run into a problem I can't seem to solve.

I need to create an extenal button that collapses all the accordions.

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", collapsible: true, active: false, autoHeight:false });
});
```

Here is what I tried on a span, which doesn't work:

```
$('.section_close').click(function() {
    $('#accordion').accordion({});
});
```

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Sorry for the noob questions, I'm a front end designer.

Here is the code that worked for me, please let me know if any of the syntax is wrong.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h1", collapsible: true, active: false, autoHeight:false });
    $('#close').click(function() {
        $('#accordion').accordion('activate', -1);
    });
});
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Activating -1 should collapse all accordion panes.

```
$('#accordion').accordion('activate', -1);
```

So you can attach that to a button click and you should be good to go!

Comment: $('.section_close').click(function() {
        $('#accordion').accordion('activate', -1);
    });

Comment: Without seeing your button, I believe that's the case. You could make a [jsfiddle](jsfiddle.net) with your accordion and button and post the link, then I could tell for sure.
I would also try putting a `console.log` message inside the `.click` event to make sure it's firing when you click the button.